# How to debug fractal tree?

Tags: javascript, debugging, html5-canvas, fractals

I need help debugging my code.

I have a create task for the AP exam. I tried giving prompts to the "undefined" ctx, angle, len, and arc, because it did not recognize these.

```
var ctx = prompt("Please enter a number between -360 and 360");
var branchWidth = prompt ("Please enter a number between one and ten");
var len = prompt ("Please enter any number between 0 and 20");
var angle = ctx;
function start() 
function draw(startX, startY, len, angle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(startX, startY);
  ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(0, -len);
  ctx.stroke();
  if (len < 10) {
    ctx.restore();
    return;
  }
  draw(0, -len, len * 0.8, -15);
  draw(0, -len, len * 0.8, 15);
  ctx.restore();
}
ctx.lineWidth = branchWidth;
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(rand";
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
if (len < 10) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, -len, 10, 0, Math.PI / 2);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();
  return;
}
draw(0, -len, len * 0.8, angle + 10, branchWidth * 0.8);
draw(0, -len, len * 0.8, angle - 10, branchWidth * 0.8);
ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)";
if (angle > 0) {
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(10, -len / 2, 10, -len / 2, 0, -len);
} else {
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(-10, -len / 2, -10, -len / 2, 0, -len);
}

start();
```

Expected program to run but instead got result:
ERROR: Line: 8: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (8:0)

Comment: Ok let me just say line 8 is still not working for me.

Comment: `function start() ` what is that line supposed to do? that isn't proper javascript, the fractal tree is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

I can make it run for you but without an explanation i can't make it work properly

```js
var angle = prompt("Please enter a number between -360 and 360");
var branchWidth = prompt ("Please enter a number between one and ten");
var len = prompt ("Please enter any number between 0 and 20");
const ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
function draw(startX, startY, len, angle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(startX, startY);
  ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(0, -len);
  ctx.stroke();
  if (len < 10) {
    ctx.restore();
    return;
  }
  draw(0, -len, len * 0.8, -15);
  draw(0, -len, len * 0.8, 15);
  ctx.restore();
}
function start() {
  ctx.lineWidth = branchWidth;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(rand";
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  if (len < 10) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, -len, 10, 0, Math.PI / 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
    return;
  }
  draw(0, -len, len * 0.8, angle + 10, branchWidth * 0.8);
  draw(0, -len, len * 0.8, angle - 10, branchWidth * 0.8);
  ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
  ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)";
  if (angle > 0) {
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(10, -len / 2, 10, -len / 2, 0, -len);
  } else {
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(-10, -len / 2, -10, -len / 2, 0, -len);
  }
}
start();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=1000 height=1000></canvas>
```

Comment: typeError ctx.beginPath is not a function